# Deleting empty Series out of Graph (with VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, graph, series

I am trying to remove all empty series out of an Excel graph.

```
    Dim isEmptySeries As Boolean
    For Series = 1 To .SeriesCollection.count
        .SeriesCollection(Series).ApplyDataLabels Type:=xlDataLabelsShowValue, AutoText:=True, LegendKey:=False
        isEmptySeries = True

        For i = 1 To .SeriesCollection(Series).points.count
            If .SeriesCollection(Series).points(i).DataLabel.Text = 0 Then
                .SeriesCollection(Series).points(i).HasDataLabel = False
            Else
                isEmptySeries = False
                .SeriesCollection(Series).points(i).DataLabel.Font.Size = 17
            End If
        Next i

        If isEmptySeries Then
                .SeriesCollection(Series).Delete
        End If
    Next Datenreihe
```

The script fails at the ApplyDatalabels line ("Method SeriesCollection of Object Chart failed").
I believe that Excel shifts the Series indexes when one of the Series is deleted? Is that the case? It's the only explanation that I have for the error.

How else would I loop through the series and remove the ones that are empty?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In these sorts of situations try looping in reverse order

```
For i = .SeriesCollection(Series).points.count To 1 Step -1
```

That way the `.Delete` doesn't effect the item yet to be looped through