# How delete a series from an Excel chart using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, charts, excel-2003

I'm trying to delete the empty series from a chart in Excel 2003 using VBA. I've seen that others have had this issue in the past and I have tried all methods mentioned in their posts but have been unable to find anything that works consistently.

The chart has 14 series in it and anywhere between 3 or 9 of them can be empty. The empty ones are always between Series 4 - 12.

I've tried a few variations of code but this is primarily it:

```
Sheets("chart-1").Select
ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
For i = 12 To 4 Step -1
    Dim theSeries As Series
    MsgBox (ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Name)
    Set theSeries = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i)
    MsgBox (theSeries.Name)
    theSeries.Delete
Next
```

I can run it successfully once for a chart, but all subsequent cycles fail with a `Unable to get the Name property of the Series class` error. It fails on the call to .Name.

I been able to get it work by inserting integers directly, but it will only run once for all integers except 1. It run it multiple times for `Series(1)`.

For instance if I simply call: ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Delete, then the series is deleted, but if I then run it with another integer (4, 9, 12) it won't run. It will work again for 1, but only 1. It will also work once with other integers (say 4), but all subsequent calls will fail even if I change the integer to 1 or keep it as 4, or change it to some other number.

The behaviour is really quite strange.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. I can't simply call `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Delete` repeatedly because the first 3 series are always non-empty.

Thanks.

** Update **

I just ran a test manually executing the following:

```
Sheets("ch-v2-12mth").Select
ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
MsgBox (ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name)
```

I cycled through the SeriesCollection trying the numbers 1 - 16 (there are only 14 Series in the chart) to see the result.
1 - 3 worked fine
4 - 13 errored with `Unable to get the Name property of the Series class`
14 worked fine
15 - 16 errored with `Method 'SeriesCollection' of object '_Chart' failed` <- not surprising given the number of series in the chart.

This type of behaviour makes me think that there is a bug with Excel. Any other ideas?

Comment: Is this what you are trying? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7875326/deleting-empty-series-out-of-graph-with-vba

Comment: @Siddharth essentially yes that's what I'm trying, without actually needing the data labels. I've updated the initial request with the results of some more tests that I've done. The results are pretty weird. Thanks for your help, but I'm still getting the same behaviour and errors. Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you opload a sample excel file so that I can play around with it? This way I will not have to create a sample file. You can upload the file in wikisend.com and then share the link here.

Comment: I just tested the code you posted, and it ran fine.

Comment: What if you reconstruct your chart in a new workbook, and rerun the code?

Comment: @SiddharthRout thanks for your help. It appears to be an issue with the order that the work sheet and chart is created. When I created a new workbook and created that chart using VB from the beginning then the code worked perfectly, but the same code won't run on a chart which was been edited using the excel/chart interface.

Comment: @Jon, thanks for your help. When I ran the code is a new workbook it ran fine, but for some reason it won't run in the original workbook. I think it has something to do with the fact that I've edited elements of the chart within excel, but I can't confirm that. The original spreadsheet is rather large and complicated and took several hours to create. Thanks again for your help and I'm sorry for taking so long to get back to you.

Answer (score 3):

There are bugs in Excel when you delete *all* the series from a chart.  My workaround is to always leave at least one series (even if it has no data in it) in the chart.  That seems to work for me.

Just thought of another thing.  When you delete a series, the indexes of all the remaining series get reduced by one, so you can't delete them by looping from 1 to the number of series.  What you can do instead is have a do loop that deletes them until the `SeriesCollection.Count = 0` (or 1, see my comments earlier).  Or a for loop that iterates backwards and always deletes the last series (i.e. `SeriesCollection(SeriesCollection.Count).Delete`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove all series or the chart will remove itself. what I do to work around this is to rename all exisiting series; then enter your code to build new stuff; then run another snippet to remove the series you renamed

```
'rename existing series
With ActiveChart
 DoEvents
    For i = .FullSeriesCollection.Count To 1 Step -1
        .FullSeriesCollection(i).Name = "remove" & i
    Next i
End With

'your code here to build new charts

'last piece of code to remove the earlier series marked for deletion
With ActiveChart
 DoEvents
    For c = .SeriesCollection.Count To 1 Step -1
        If .SeriesCollection(c).Name Like "*Series*" Then .SeriesCollection(c).Delete
    Next c
End With
'also, you need to step backwards because each time you remove a series it will re-index
```

Comment: don't forget your Doevents and Step -1

Comment: Do you possibly mean `If .SeriesCollection(c).Name Like "remove*" then ...`?

Comment: You _can_ remove all series. The chart will remain, but it will be blank until you add more data. Many of the elements that disappeared when the data was cleared will have lost formatting, and titles will have lost their text.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code to this:

```
Sheets("chart-1").Select
For i = 12 To 4 Step -1
    MsgBox "Series " & i & ": """ ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Name & """"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Delete
Next
```

I don't know why the code was not working for you, but simpler is usually better. And you don't need to know the series name to delete a series.